# Edit view fails within try block and goes straight to return with no error

Tags: python, flask

I'm struggling to build an edit CRUD view in Flask. I have the add and list view working fine:

```
@main_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_items():
    all_user_items = Items.query.filter_by()
    return render_template('main/items.html', items=all_user_items)

@main_blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_item():
    form = ItemsForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                new_item = Items(form.name.data, form.notes.data)
                db.session.add(new_item)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Item added', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                flash('Something went wrong', 'danger')
    return render_template('main/add.html', form=form)
```

But when designing the edit item view, it simply reroutes me back to the list view.

```
@main_blueprint.route('/edit_item/<items_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_item(items_id):
    form = EditItemsForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                item = Items.query.get(items_id)
                item.name = form.name.data
                item.notes = form.notes.data
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Item edited successfully!', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                flash('Unable to edit item', 'danger')
        return render_template('edit_item.html', item=item, form=form)
    else:
        flash('Something went wrong', 'danger')
    return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
```

The log doesn't give any clues either even though I have full debug

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022 10:32:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2022 10:32:29] "GET /static/images/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Based on previous conversations, it sounds like it is failing within the TRY block and going straight to the last line. Code in context is here:

https://github.com/hiven/FlaskApp/blob/d9fce1b123f38aabbc48c63659a880a58b2fe44e/app/main/views.py

Comment: In your `main/items.html` do you have a correctly working code block that prints flashed messages? My suggestion is to replace flash calls with print() calls so that it becomes easier to see the errors where they actually occurred. Also, you don't have to check post request using `request.method == POST`. Running `form.validate_on_submit()` does this check automatically.  // There's also this thing with GET request in this view....

Comment: In your else condition you would want to return "Access forbidden" or something, because otherwise, you yourself might get confused sometime later as to why your items.html is flashing `Something went wrong` without telling what actually went wrong. :)

Comment: Hi Firelord. Good tips, thank you. With respect to your first comment yes I have a main items html. Full code is here https://github.com/hiven/FlaskApp/blob/9ddee744d3af2865e2952c41a085e6ff3f8e503a/app/main/templates/main/edit_item.html

Comment: You're redirecting in the `try` block `return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))`

Comment: @NizamMohamed So that shoudlnt appear in try, and only at the bottom

Comment: Put whatever you want to do upon success in an `else` block below `except` block.

Comment: Do you see the new edits  in the list view? If you do it means editing works

Comment: @NizamMohamed Hello. No the edits aren’t made, in fact I don’t even see the edit form, it immediately redirects me back to that list page

Answer (score 1):

On GET request the last line `return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))` in `edit_item` takes you to the list view.

I've simplified the code by removing some unnecessary lines.

```
@main_blueprint.route("/edit_item/<items_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_item(items_id):
    form = EditItemsForm(request.form)
    try:
        item = Items.query.get(items_id)
    except Exception:
        flash("Unable to edit item", "danger")
        return redirect(url_for("main.all_items"))
    # if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            item.name = form.name.data
            item.notes = form.notes.data
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash("Unable to edit item", "danger")
        else:
            flash("Item edited successfully!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("main.all_items"))
    return render_template("edit_item.html", item=item, form=form)
    # else:
    #     flash('Something went wrong', 'danger')
    # return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried running the code but it says : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hiven/ce1848de1d726e2a92b7517cfab5ecbb/raw/9244a7704088895c2276c061ac69ff31acccb391/gistfile1.txt

Comment: To clarify, the main error was : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment

Comment: Fixed `UnboudLocalError`.